# Cannot force install GD with cpan/cpanm

Tags: perl, gd, perl-module, cpan

I have looked and seen similar issues posted but am unable to get GD working. the following error arises **with libgd and libpng installed**...

```
clang -c  -I/usr/local/include -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -Wformat=0 -Os   -DVERSION=\"2.50\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.50\"  "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_FT -DHAVE_GIF -DHAVE_ANIMGIF -DVERSION_33 -DHAVE_UNCLOSEDPOLY -DHAVE_FTCIRCLE GD.c
GD.xs:997:18: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gdImageGifAnimBeginPtr' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        data = (void *) gdImageGifAnimBeginPtr(image,&size,globalcm,loops);
                        ^
GD.xs:1022:18: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gdImageGifAnimAddPtr' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        data = (void *) gdImageGifAnimAddPtr(image,&size,localcm,leftofs,topofs,delay,disposal,previm);
                        ^
GD.xs:1041:18: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gdImageGifAnimEndPtr' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        data = (void *) gdImageGifAnimEndPtr(&size);
                        ^
GD.xs:1598:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gdImageOpenPolygon' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                gdImageOpenPolygon(image,polyptr,length,color);
                ^
GD.xs:2192:16: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
            if (value = hv_fetch(hash,"linespacing",strlen("linespacing"),0)) {
                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
GD.xs:2192:16: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
            if (value = hv_fetch(hash,"linespacing",strlen("linespacing"),0)) {
                      ^
                (                                                           )
```

...

```
2 warnings generated.
rm -f blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.bundle
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib" clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.8  -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector GD.o  -o blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.bundle    \
       -L/usr/local/lib -lz -liconv -lgd    \

ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgd.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libgd.dylib
chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.bundle
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- GD.bs blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.bs 644
/usr/bin/perl "-Iblib/arch" "-Iblib/lib" bdf_scripts/bdf2gdfont.PLS bdf_scripts/bdf2gdfont.pl
Extracting bdf2gdfont.pl (with variable substitutions)
cp bdf_scripts/bdf2gdfont.pl blib/script/bdf2gdfont.pl
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/bdf2gdfont.pl
Manifying blib/man1/bdf2gdfont.pl.1
Manifying blib/man3/GD.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/GD::Image.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/GD::Polygon.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/GD::Polyline.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/GD::Simple.3pm
Running Mkbootstrap for GD ()
chmod 644 GD.bs
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
Testing using gif support.
t/GD.t ........ 
Failed 6/12 subtests 
    (less 3 skipped subtests: 3 okay)
t/Polyline.t .. ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/GD.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 12 Failed: 6)
  Failed tests:  2-7
Files=2, Tests=13,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.10 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.14 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/2 test programs. 6/13 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
-> FAIL Installing GD failed. See /Users/lraven/.cpanm/work/1391048234.74068/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
Expiring 19 work directories.
```

All other modules I need are installing, just not GD.

I am using OS X 10.8.5, bash version 3.2.48, perl version 5.012 and cpanm version 1.7

Comment: You've installed libgd, of course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can install GD the Perl module you must have installed a number of other libraries first, including the gd graphics library itself ([libgd](http://www.boutell.com/gd/)), the PNG library ([libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)) and optionally the JPEG and FreeType libraries.

You will probably find it easier to use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to install these libraries, and you can then install GD from there too - the package is called p5.14-gd (or whatever matches your perl version)

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful suggestion, i was not aware that I needed to install this separately. I am not longer getting errors with the image stuff but it still has not installed correctly. Are there any other packages I need?

Comment: Thanks tangent, I have updated the error above. Unfortunately its difficult to decipher. i asked if anymore modules are required because it seems to have a problem with MExtUtils::MY which is not listed in my perl modules. There is alot of information in these log files and it is unclear what the error is...

Comment: "ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgd.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)" - looks like you haven't installed the gd library properly, I would recommend you use MacPorts

Comment: I was trying to avoid macports because all the help blogs using macports said to use cpanm... 
Following your suggestions i have tried macports and have been able to install gd2 and libgd5! which i hope are analogous to gd and libgd... 

If you would be willing to help me with one last step? 
gd2 --version does not work, or "whereis gd2". 

`lraven$ sudo /opt/local/bin/port installed`
`libgda5 @5.2.2_0+db51 (active)`
`gd2 @2.1.0_4+x11 (active)`
`libpng @1.6.8_0 (active)`


So how do I get perl to recognise these modules now? I could put them in $PATH but i cannot find them...

Comment: gd2 is what you need, so add /opt/local/bin and /opt/local/sbin to $PATH. You should also add to your bash profile see [this page](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.shell)

Comment: Worked a charm! I cannot thank you enough. I still cannot actually find the GD module but not a problem so long as circos can. 

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this - To get circos to work I did the following.... 
1/ I installed all modules using cpanm

`wget -O- http://cpanmin.us | perl - -l ~/perl5 App::cpanminus local::lib`

```
eval `perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib`
cpanm Config::General
cpanm Font::TTF
cpanm List::MoreUtils
cpanm Math::Bezier
cpanm Math::Round
cpanm Math::VecStat
cpanm Params::Validate
cpanm Readonly
cpanm Regexp::Common
cpanm Set::IntSpan 
cpanm Text::Format
cpanm Clone
cpanm GD
echo 'eval `perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib`' >> ~/.profile
```

GD would not install. To fix this: 
I Downloaded and installed macports from http://www.macports.org/install.php

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/port install gd2
sudo /opt/local/bin/port install jpeg
sudo /opt/local/bin/port install libpng
sudo /opt/local/bin/port install libgda5
```

I got an error associated with gnome desktop and ran
`sudo /opt/local/bin/port clean gnome-desktop` then reinstalled libgd

Finally, to get GD to a spot where perl will find it…

`export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`